# How to extract Subject from PEM file using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, x509certificate

I'm trying to extract the Subject Name of a certificate from the PEM format using NodeJS, in the standard format, which should look like 
    "C=US, ST=California, L=San Francisco, O=Wikimedia Foundation, Inc., CN=*.wikipedia.org"

I am able to extract the subject name using the x509-package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/x509), and then the command

```
var subject = x509.getSubject(pem_cert);
```

however, this formats it as such

```
{ commonName: '*.wikipedia.org',
  serialNumber: 'some_number',
  countryName: 'US' 
}
```

I need the format to be equal to the standard format, is there a NodeJS package or command that will have that specific output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the certificate subject in the required format by using [node-forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge)

```
const pki = require('node-forge').pki;


const certPem = `
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
your certificate here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
`;

const cert = pki.certificateFromPem(certPem);
const subject = cert.subject.attributes
  .map(attr => [attr.shortName, attr.value].join('='))
  .join(', ');

console.log(subject); // "C=US, ST=California, ..."
```

If you have [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) command line utility available on the OS where Node.js is running you can invoke it to get the subject string as well:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');


const certPem = `
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
your certificate here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
`;

const child = spawn('openssl', ['x509', '-subject', '-noout']);

child.stdin.write(certPem);

let data = '';
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf-8');
child.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
  data += chunk
});

child.on('close', () => {
  const subject = data.replace(/^subject=/, '');
  console.log(subject);
});

child.stdin.end();
```

Comment: This almost works! It turns the output into 
CN=*.wikipedia.org, =some_number, C=US
so it skips serialNumber. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Also seems to be in a different order (from the standard), however I can't really find how much of this is standardised

Comment: I am afraid I am not aware about this standard. Can you please share details about it? What I know is that [serialNumber](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.2) that must be presented in every certificate is not a part of the [subject](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.6). However, **subject** may optionally contain [serialNumber](https://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.5.4.5.html) which is a different number.

Comment: With `node-forge` you can access the mandatory `serialNumber` as `cert.serialNumber` and the serial number that may be included in the subject should be available in `cert.subject.attributes`.

Comment: @Krijn I have also updated the answer with another approach to get the subject string that leverages `openssl`. Probably it will meet your requirement better.

Comment: After looking into it, there seems to be no standard (or at least multiple ones). You are indeed correct and your other approach (leveraging openssl) is much better for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, I'm glad to know that `openssl` approach worked, you are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Since nodejs 15.6, you would better use the standard `crypto` module:
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#x509subject

```
const crypto = require("crypto")
const cert = new crypto.X509Certificate(fs.readFileSync('my.crt')))

console.log(cert.subject)
// Gives 'C=ES\nO=The Cert Corp\nCN=example.com'
```